# In SwiftUI, how can I perform a gesture but forward gestures to the view behind it?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am creating a tooltip system.

I want to dismiss the tooltip if the user touches anywhere outside the tooltip.

I would like it so that a touch outside the tooltip both dismisses the tooltip and activates any controls the user tapped on. (So you could have a tooltip open and still click a button outside the tooltip and have it activate on the first tap.)

To do this, I have an invisible view handling the tap gesture and dismissing the tooltip, but I do not know how to make SwiftUI not intercept and cancel the tap gestures. On the web, it's the equivalent of not calling `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`, or [calling super in `touchesBegan:` in UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

Here is a demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Button") { print("> button tapped")}
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())       // makes all area tappable
        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({
             print(">>> tooltip area here")
        }))
        .border(Color.red)   // just for demo show area
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx. You saved my day. I had a problem with PDFView and button over it which didn't accept touch event.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use this modifier:

```
.allowsHitTesting(false)
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I need to allow hit testing in order to handle the tap gesture to dismiss the tooltip. But I also want my tap to affect views behind that view.